# Counting pattern matches for elements in awk array

Tags: arrays, awk

I need some help in fixing my code to process a tab-delimited data set. Example data is:

```
#ID type
A   3
A   Ct
A   Ct
A   chloroplast
B   Ct
B   Ct
B   chloroplast
B   chloroplast
B   4
C   Ct
C   Ct
C   chloroplast
```

For each unique element in column#1, I would like to count elements that matches the pattern "Ct" and those that don't match.
So expected output is

```
#ID  count_for_matches count_for_unmatched
A   2   2
B   2   3
C   2   1
```

I can get the counts to pattern matches with this

```
awk '$2~/Ct/{x++};$2!~/Ct/{y++}END{print x,y}
```

And I know I could do the processing for each item by defining column#1 as an array like

```
awk '{a[$1]++}END{for (i in a) print i}'
```

But I cannot combine both pieces for a functional code. I tried some combinations like

```
awk '{a[$1]++}END{for (i in a){$2~/Ct/{x++};$2!~/Ctt/{y++}}END{print i,x,y}}}'
```

But I am obviously making some errors and I cannot figure out based on forum answers how to fix this. Perhaps $2 values should be stored with a[$1]? Would appreciate if someone can point out the errors!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
NR==1 { next }
!seen[$1]++ { keys[++numKeys] = $1 }
$2=="Ct" { matches[$1]++; next }
{ unmatched[$1]++ }
END {
    print "#ID", "count_for_matches", "count_for_unmatched"
    for (keyNr=1; keyNr<=numKeys; keyNr++) {
        key = keys[keyNr]
        print key, matches[key]+0, unmatched[key]+0
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
#ID     count_for_matches       count_for_unmatched
A       2       2
B       2       3
C       2       1
```

Answer (score 2):

here is another minimalist version

```
$ awk 'NR==1{print $1,"count_for_matches","count_for_unmatches";next}
    $2=="Ct"{m[$1]++} 
            {a[$1]++} 
         END{for(k in a) print k, m[k], a[k]-m[k]}' file | 
 column -t

#ID  count_for_matches  count_for_unmatches
A    2                  2
B    2                  3
C    2                  1
```